# How do MU-MIMO and beamforming work together when they have seemingly opposite goals?

Tags: wireless-networking

Please help me understand how MU-MIMO and beamforming work together when they have seemingly opposite goals. The way beamforming is implemented in Wi-Fi 5/6 APs is, they will always prioritize spatial multiplexing, for instance a 4x4 router will give a 2x2 client 2 data streams. Then it may use its other 2 antennas to send the same 2x2 stream again slightly offset, so it's now essentially a 2-antenna phased array, and if you have 2 dbi antennas you will get a 2 + 3 = 5 dbi gain from the array (2 dbi from the antenna's gain, and 3 dbi is from the doubling of antennas transmitting the same signal).

Alternatively, the 4x4 AP can use only one antenna for beamforming and send the 2x2 client its 2 data streams with 2 + 1.75 = 3.75 dbi gain. (1.75 dbi = 50% increase). And then it has 1 spare antenna to serve a 1x1 client and cannot use beamforming on that client. For a 3x3 client, it can do weak beamforming and then not serve any other clients at the same time, and for a 4x4 client it can't do beamforming or serve any other clients.

So there's a clear bottleneck. Even high performance routers have at most 4x4 antennas. Few very expensive ones will have 8x8 but it's very rare. And almost all clients today are at least 2x2. MU-MIMO uses independent data streams. Beamforming uses identical data streams. Yes they work together (in fact you cannot enable MU-MIMO without enabling explicit beamforming), but they use each other's resources.

So how can you be serving multiple clients at the same time with a 4x4 router when just to serve one 2x2 client you need all of your antennas for +3 dbi, or you can use 3 and then have one that can't beamform on its own

I have a theory. Routers "lie" to their clients and tell them they're connected at 2x2, 3x3, or 4x4 at some PHY link rate, when in fact they're all connected at 1x1 and the other antennas are used for beamforming. So the router puts all users on time division multiplexing and then it does beamforming with all but 1 antennas until that antenna's bandwidth fills up. Then MU-MIMO kicks in, activating another antenna, then offloading half the traffic to that antenna (at this point 2x2 clients are using both antennas for increased performance and two 1x1 clients are getting simultaneous data streams), the rest of the antennas are still used for beamforming. When those 2 antennas fill up, a third antenna is transferred from beamforming duty to data stream duty, now 3x3 clients can use 3 antennas and 3 simultaneous streams can be sent to 1, 2 or 3 separate users. And so on until the last antenna activates and then you get no beamforming.

At every step, you should notice a small drop in signal strength. I think I've noticed this before, but I thought it was just natural fluctuations of the RF environment.

Am I on the right track with my thinking? Antennas aren't assigned to clients, rather antennas "fill up" while the rest are used for beamforming. Maybe not ideal for latency, but it's efficient and you still get full bandwidth. But this doesn't explain why you can't enable MU-MIMO without beamforming, why is beamforming strictly necessary? Without beamforming, you should be able to start "filling up" all antennas from the start, making the system a little more responsive at the expense of signal strength. You already get no beamforming once all of your antennas are active for data. The opposite is possible, you can disable MU-MIMO but keep explicit beamforming on, if you really want to prioritize signal strength. So why isn't the opposite possible?

Sorry for the wall of text. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something? Please let me know how MU-MIMO and beamforming actually work effectively together. Most articles make it seem like beamforming and MU-MIMO are not mutually exclusive but rather 2 sides of the same coin, i.e. antennas can do both at the same time, they can send phase-shifted discrete data streams. But my research shows that's not possible, let me know if that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

First, terminology. An antenna is just a passive chunk of metal. Even non-MIMO (SISO) systems can have multiple antennas, for things like receive diversity. What makes MIMO systems special is not just that they have multiple antennas, but that each antenna has a separate *radio chain* powering, and those radio chains are all working together in the same wireless interface (WNIC).

Second, it's super useful to realize that 802.11 was always designed to be TDMA (Time Division Multiple Access, a.k.a. Time Division Multiplexing, a.k.a. "everyone takes turns transmitting"), and is still primarily TDMA today. So for a quarter century now, APs have happily served multiple clients "simultaneously" just by everyone taking turns transmitting on the channel. This turn-taking is not a problem, because packet lengths are limited to make sure no one stays on the medium for too long, and there are rules that make access to the medium reasonably fair.

Now, about assigning MIMO radio chains to beamforming vs. spatial streams:

On MIMO systems, for each transmission, each radio chain can either be used for an additional spatial stream, or to do beamforming, but not both on the same transmission. This is true of all MIMO systems that are capable of multiple spatial streams as well as beamforming. This is not something new or specific to MU-MIMO.

The IEEE 802.11 standards ("Wi-Fi" is mostly just an industry marketing name for 802.11) don't specify an algorithm to use to make those trade-offs. It's left as an implementation detail. So every vendor might have a different algorithm for when they choose to transmit a packet using some of their radio chains for beamforming, and when they choose to transmit a packet using all their radio chains for spatial streams.

The decisions can be made on packet-by-packet basis, more or less. Nowadays packets are often transmitted in aggregate frames, so like a small burst of packets at a time. Each time a device transmits either a single packet or an aggregate containing multiple packets, it's called a Transmit Operation or TXOP. So the decisions are made on a TXOP-by-TXOP basis.

When a client device associates to (joins) an AP, they communicate their capabilities to each other, like whether they each support beamforming, and how many spatial streams they are capable of. That gives each device a list of possible transmission modes it can use when it needs to transmit a packet to the other device. So each device, when it has a packet queued to transmit to the other device, hopefully considers recent RF conditions and other factors, and hopefully chooses whichever transmission mode is likely to be most airtime-efficient, hopefully taking into account the cost of potential loss and retransmission. But again, that's all left up to the implementors, so everyone might be doing it differently, and many cheap devices may be using brain-dead algorithms that suck.

Note that there is no real established "link rate"; if you have a client device that reports a link rate with the AP, what it's usually doing is looking at all the different capabilities the client and the AP share, and reporting the speed of the fastest transmission mode they both support, even if that transmission mode is not currently viable due to low signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). Sometimes you can get your devices to tell you not just that maximum transmission speed they both support, but also the speed of the transmission mode it's recently been using for that link (so more like the effective link rate rather than the potential max link rate). So no AP "lies" to any client about a link rate. They don't negotiate a link rate, they just communicate a list of their own capabilities to each other.

Comment: Great reply, thank you. So they each have a proprietary method of allocating data and beamforming radio chains. I guess they may do some version of what I described if they're trying to prioritize beamforming, and maybe if extra signal strength isn't needed for anyone (because of good RSSI or low data usage), they prioritize parallel data streams. Though again, with TDM and enough bandwidth, a client shouldn't be able to tell the difference between MIMO and SISO, other than a negligible amount of latency? There are so many variables in this...